# How to detect Visual Studio Express with CMAKE

Tags: cmake

The title is pretty much self explanatory. I need to detect VS Express to disable some features that aren't available in Express.

Comment: Which features?  I'm not aware of anything an a solution or project file that would prevent VS Express from opening it.  And I'm not aware of any compiler differences.

Comment: @John ATL isn't available in express

Comment: Have you tried [CMAKE_USING_VC_FREE_TOOLS](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-May/044338.html)?

Comment: @John tried and confirmed that CMAKE_USING_VC_FREE_TOOLS does not work.

Comment: On top of that looks like CMAKE_USING_VC_FREE_TOOLS isn't referenced in entire CMAKE installation folder.

Comment: @John... For example: in Visual Studio 2010 Express you can't group your projects in folders...

Answer (score 0):

In CMake, the philosophy is to detect features directly and then define variables that indicate the presence of those features.  You use the variable to adjust your build.

In this case, the feature is ATL, so what you want to do is not identify the free version of Visual Studio, but detect the presence of ATL on the system.  You can do this in a number of ways:

1. Look for a header file specific to ATL
2. Look for a directory specific to ATL
3. Look for a library specific to ATL

Here is an example that uses the 2nd approach:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(foo CXX)

get_filename_component(_vc_bin_dir ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} DIRECTORY)
get_filename_component(_vc_dir ${_vc_bin_dir} DIRECTORY)
set(_vc_atlmfc ${_vc_dir}/atlmfc)
if(IS_DIRECTORY ${_vc_atlmfc})
    message(STATUS "You have ATL/MFC available in ${_vc_atlmfc}.")
else()
    message(STATUS "You don't have ATL/MFC.")
endif()

add_executable(a a.cpp)
```

`get_filename_component` is a CMake 3.0 command, hence the required version 3.0.